# Can't get radio buttons to work in PHPmailer

Tags: php

First off, I'm not a programming expert by any means. I had a company set PHPmailer for me and they created a simple form and the php code that makes it work. They didn't include radio buttons in the example and I haven't been able to figure out how to make them work.
I believe it's something simple but still over my head.
The link to the webpage: https://rappahannockfoundation.org/pages/opinion.php

Form code:

```
<form method="post" action="frmCode_opinion.php">
<p>Which concert did you attend? Click only one.</p>
  <p>
    <input name="concert" type="radio" value="Face 2 Face">
    <label for="Face2Face">Face 2 Face</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="concert" ivalue="Capitol Steps">
    <label for="CapitolSteps">Capitol Steps</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="concert" value="Russian String Orchestra">
    <label for="RussianStringOrchestra">Russian String Orchestra</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="concert" value="Motones vs. Jerseys">
    <label for="MotonesJerseys">Motones vs. Jerseys</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="concert" value="Leahy">
    <label for="Leahy">Leahy</label></p>
     <p>
    
  <p class="padding_top_10">Would you like to see them for a return performance?</p>
  <p><input name="return" type="radio"  value="YES"> <label for="return">Yes </label>
  <input name="return" type="radio"  value="NO"> <label for="return">No </label>
  </p>
  <p class="padding_top_10">Please rate this program. 1 is poor 5 is excellent.</p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1"><label for="one">1 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2"><label for="two">2 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3"><label for="three">3 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="4"><label for="four">4 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="5"><label for="five">5 </label>
  </p>
  <p class="padding_top_10">Please provide comments or suggestions for future performances. 

</p>
    <textarea style="margin-left:20px;" name="comments" cols="70" rows="5" id="comments"></textarea>
    <p><div class="g-recaptcha padding_left_20 marginTop_20" data-sitekey="6LcXnhUUAAAAANRPRnVnY0sZEedUEvsr5lL80Zcj"></div></p>
     
       <p> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    
    </form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
 
/**
 * This example shows how to handle a simple contact form using PHPMailer.
 */

//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$msg = '';
//Don't run this unless we're handling a form submission
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    // the below files are required in order to perform SMTP authentication using the PHPMailer library. If your page/script is under a subdirectory, rather than at the root of the Website directory, then you will need to update the paths here accordingly. For example, if your contact form is located under "/contact/form.php" then you should use a format like: "../phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php"
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    
    

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance, the following lines will remain the same for all sites on your Plesk server
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'secure.emailsrvr.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    //$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true; 
    
    //CAPTCHA CODE
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
 }
if(!$captcha){  $err = "1"; 
}
$secretKey = "6LcXnhUUAAAAACRJ2RZ4A2CJmCFdNVxDfV4EbLPx";
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) { 
$err = "1"; 
}
    
    
    // This will send information from the web server if form doesn't work 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; //this one is best
    
    // The below parameters must be updated per Website:
    // Username (address) and Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'dave@lmarketing.com';
    $mail->Password = 'Cr0ssT0ur!';

    //Use the same "Username" fixed address in your own domain as the from address
    $mail->setFrom('info@lmarketing.com', 'Dave Lipscombe');
    //Set the recipient for this email (any email address and name)
    $mail->addAddress('dave@lmarketing.com', 'Dave Lipscombe');
    $mail->addBCC('lurbanna@gmail.com', 'Dave Lipscombe');
    
    //Put the submitter's address in a reply-to header
    //This will fail if the address provided is invalid,
    //in which case we should ignore the whole request
    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = 'Submission from RFA Website';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        //Build HTML message body
        $emailMessage = "";
        $emailMessage .= "<p>Concert: {$_POST['concert']}</p>";
        $emailMessage .= "<p>Return performance: {$_POST['return']}</p>";
        $emailMessage .= "<p>Program rating: {$_POST['rate']}</p>";
        $emailMessage .= "<p>Comments: {$_POST['comments']}</p>"; 
    
        // store the complete message string in the email body
        $mail->Body = $emailMessage;
        
        //set non-html message text for fallback in non-html compatible email software
        //Build a simple message body
        $mail->AltBody = <<<EOT
Concert: {$_POST['concert']}
Return Performance: {$_POST['return']}
Program rating: {$_POST['rate']}
Program rating: {$_POST['rate']}
Comments: {$_POST['comments']}
EOT;
        //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            //If you need to debug an error sending, the reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo. Uncomment the below line to enable detailed error reporting, but be warned, this will display detailed error messages to anyone who uses the form while enabled!
            print_r($mail->ErrorInfo); //comment this line when not in-use
            //but you shouldn't display the details of those errors to users, so only this generic message will display publicly
            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            header("Location: thanks.php");
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }
}
// Below you will find an example form, which includes the basic fields being sent in the email body above.
?>
```

Comment: You should not provide `$secretsKey` here. However, what exactly is the problem with your program? Is it a problem in the HTML part (GUI) or with the backend (PHP)? You HTML labels do not address the correct radio buttons. You have to use the input's id in the `for` attribute.

Comment: When I click submit it just stops at the phpMailer page and doesn't send the email. I assumed it was because the radio buttons in the php code weren't correct.

Comment: And you are correct, I totally forgot the reCaptch info was in there. Not too smart.